# Simple GTK application on Beaglebone black has a blank white window

Tags: gtk, beagleboneblack

I am starting to develop for Beaglebone Black and have just written a test application for GTK:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
      GtkWidget *window;

      gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

      window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
      gtk_widget_show(window);

      gtk_main();

      return 0;
}
```

I compile using

```
gcc -o simple simple.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`
```

and that succeeds as expected. However when I run the application on my BBB (running Angstrom), all I get is a white square at the top left of my display. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent this afternoon battling the same issue and I found a solution that worked for me.  The solution proposed here: [BeagleBoard forum post](http://beagleboard.org/Community/Forums?place=msg%2Fbeagleboard%2FrIkQYTEFrEI%2FLCzk-goM-kcJ) is to switch window managers from gdm to xcfe.  Here is a transcript of the steps:

```
1) Install lxdm

# opkg install lxdm

2)  Disable gdm

# systemctl disable gdm.service

3) Enable lxdm

# systemctl enable lxdm

4)  install xcfe 

# opkg install packagegroup-xfce-base

5)  reboot and then when you get the login screen in the lower left make sure you select en for language and xfce for desktop otherwise it just brings you back to the login prompt - you should not know how long it took me to figure that one out....
```

I just finished testing this method and it worked for me: [image: Screenshot of it working]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your BBB isn't running a window manager and you're just seeing the undecorated and empty window. Try adding some widgets to the window and see if they appear

```
window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_title("Hello World!");
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button);
gtk_widget_show (button);

gtk_widget_show (window);
```

Try running it on a normal desktop and see if that meets your expectations

Comment: OK so running that adds a button to the window, which is progress! I am a little puzzled as to why there is no title bar on the window because just about every sample has a title and a border: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/firstprograms/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same problem on the latest Angstrom build for BBB (2013-09-04). Switched to Debian build and everything works out OK. It might be the Gnome version but I dont have enough Linux experience to confirm this